# How store objects that should be identical in two or more data structures

Tags: c++, vector

Say I want to create a college class that contains a vector of students:

```
class College {

   vector<Student> _students;
}
```

In addition to the students vector, I also want to create a MAP where the key is the student and the value is his grades.

```
  map<Student,size_t> _student_grades;
```

The problem is that it looks kinda inefficient to hold two copies of the same student in both data structures (The map and the vector).
I thought about making the vector the 'main' data structure for the students and the map will only contain a pointer to a student and its grade.

Something like:

```
map<Student*,size_t> _student_grades;
```

Big disadvantage ofc, is when I remove a student object from the vector I should instantly remove it from the map as well to avoid a pointer that points to 'nothing'.

I would love to hear some alternative solutions to the problem or improvements to mine..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not create a Custom vector?

Comment: Why do you think removing student from the map is a big disadvantage?

Comment: Depending on the operations you want to perform, it could be sufficient with the `map<Student, size_t>`. After all, you can iterate over every key-value pair to get all the `Student` objects.

Comment: Your proposed solution sounds right, you just need to abstract it away inside a class so it does not get used erroneously

Comment: Making it private and prevent access to it through methods should do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the vector and simply use the map:

```
class College {
   std::map<Student,size_t> _student_grades;
}
```

This prevents you from having to maintain parallel data structures.

You can iterate over your map keys like:

```
std::map<Student, size_t>::iterator it_type;
for(it_type iterator = _student_grades.begin(); iterator != _student_grades.end(); iterator++)
{
    // iterator->first = Student
    // iterator->second = size_t
}
```

You can test to see if a student is in the map like:

```
if (_student_grades.find(some_student) == _student_grades.end())
{
   // Student has no record in map yet.
}
```

There is more overhead to using a map over a vector however less overhead to using just a map compared to maintaining both.